# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n c_n$ converges for all $a=(a_n)\in l^1(\mathbb{N})$ then $c$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $c=(c_n)\subset \mathbb{C}$ and suposse that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n c_n$ converges  for all $a=(a_n)\in l^1(\mathbb{N})$. Show that $c$ is bounded.

Hi. I cannot conclude on this problem. I attach the possible ideas I have.

Idea: For all $k$, $|c_k|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{k} |a_n||c_n|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nc_n$ with $a=(\frac{\overline{c_1}}{|c_1|},\ldots, \frac{\overline{c_k}}{|c_k|},0,\ldots, )\in l^1(\mathbb{N})$
and I would like to consider $b$ as $b=(\frac{\overline{c_1}}{|c_1|},\ldots, \frac{\overline{c_k}}{|c_k|},\ldots)$ but this $b\not\in l^1(\mathbb{N})$... and that does not allow me to obtain a bound for $| c_k|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c$ is not bounded then there must be a subsequence $(c_{n_k})$ such that $|c_{n_k}|>k^2$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Now define $(a_n)$ like this:

$a_n=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{k^2} &,  n=n_k \\ 0 & \text{,otherwise} \end{cases}$

Clearly $(a_n)\in\ell^1$. However, note that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $|a_{n_k}c_{n_k}|>1$. So the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nc_n$ can't converge, as its general term doesn't even tend to zero. So we have a contradiction.